# How to implement the OAuth2 Authorization code grant for a React single page application?

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0, single-page-application, openid-connect

I have a task to implement OAuth2 Authorization Code flow for our React UI. we have our organization custom Oauth2 provider (which only accept Authorization Code grant type). I don't want to implement the OIDC logic manually, I saw that a lot of example that use oidc-client library on implicit grant, but I couldn't find a good example that implement the Authorization Code flow.

Could I use the oidc-client library on Authorization Code grant type? any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use oidc-client with the authorization code flow (PKCE) - my [code example](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample1) shows how.

In 2021 though it is recommended to use a [Back End for Front End](https://curity.io/resources/learn/back-end-for-front-end-example/) approach instead, for these 2 reasons:

- Avoid usability problems caused by recent browser restrictions that drop the SSO cookie
- Take advantage of recent browser changes to SameSite cookies, for stronger security

Using an API driven BFF works best - but this is a deeper topic than you may think.

Comment: Thank you Gary. That's very help.